# How can I set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5120M in the project gradle.properties?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle.properties

I'm getting this

> To run dex in the process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.

error and I want to add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5120M` to my gradle.properties to fix this issue. However, I can't find the `gradle.properties` file in my project.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37389861/2949612

Comment: I think set a giant heap is not good for your computer. 1024M would be better and enough to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can help with the above.

Changing the gradle heap size will not assist you so much  but you can try this two ways to evade this type of error 'Gradle daemon' error.

Close all other application running and restart the android studio. If the error persist, use the second method.

That is close unnecessary processes running on the background by holding down alt+ctrl and then click del button to open the task manager window.

Mostly, browsers tend to run on the background and consume alot of memory that is why you see that Gradle daemon error.

For example, close chrome process which is running on the background and either restart the android studio or rebuild the project

Answer (score 2):

File `gradle.properties` is in the top level of your project files.

For example - On Microsoft Windows, with project `MyApplication`, look in:

```
C:\Users\your Windows user name\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\gradle.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the gradle.properties on your user directory, for example (on Windows):

C:\Users<your-user-name-here>.gradle\gradle.properties