# Android Material and appcompat Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have next grade

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
}
```

But when I want to build app I get next log:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha3] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha3] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

Okey! Go to manifest and do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ru.chopcode.myapplication">

    <application
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Then I get this error in my Logcat:

```
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs that I have Linked with it
```

Comment: Try removing these lines:   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'   and    
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

Comment: I think material packages are all bundled into android-design, check it out...

Comment: I need this: https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html. This is into android-design?

Comment: You can check this one too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54825603/1318946

Comment: New android studio have feature to migrate your application to androidX smoothly. follow below link.

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/193#issuecomment-451296773

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just change "rc01" in first and last line inside dependencies to "alpha1"
This is working for me

Comment: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/androidx.core_core.version

Comment: I dont have "rc01" written in implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'. Still getting the issue. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: This answer should have been a comment to the question.

Answer (score 485):

I had similar problem. Added two lines in `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

These two lines automatically resolved my dependency conflicts between google's files and third party dependencies. Here's the link to follow: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-overview#new-project

Comment: after added this following error happens
``` * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-camera:compileGeneralDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: @PrinceHamza check this we found a solution for this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25292#issuecomment-503070043

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This solved the problem.

Comment: "But I don't see a 'gradles.properties file' "!. Yes, so in the app's root folder in studio project , create that file (no extension) and adds those lines.

Comment: After do this I have got `Could not set unknown property 'useAndroidX' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.` error

Comment: it worked for me but i have to change all tags in xml files that use support library like constraintLayout and toolbar and in the java classes either! it take a long time.

Comment: android.enableJetifier=true worked for me ... the androidX reference was already there. +1

Answer (score 148):

I faced same error when i try to add Kotlin-KTX library to my project.

I try to AndroidX migration, and problem fixed!

[image: Refactor/Migrate to AndroidX]

Comment: This works, but some of the import statements that it generates use outdated package names. I had to fix a bunch of them, just by using whichever `androidx.*` package name the IDE suggested as a fix.

Comment: I ran into this issue because I was pulling the latest release of "support-v4" library in my build.gradle file...not a good practice.  Had I been referencing a specific version of the library within my gradle file, I would have never run into this issue in the first place.  Also, after I researched a little more, I could see that Google was recommending switching to the AndroidX library; so, I decided to bite the bullet.  Fortunately, all problems resolved after the upgrade...disaster averted and LESSON LEARNED about the gradle references.

Answer (score 110):

#### Reason of Fail

You are using material library which is part of [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/).
If you are not aware of AndroidX, please go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563).

> One app should use either AndroidX or old Android Support libraries.
> That's why you faced this issue.

For example -

In your gradle, you are using

- `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` (Part of old --Android Support Library--)
- `com.google.android.material:material` (Part of AndroidX) (AndroidX build artifact of `com.android.support:design`)

#### Solution

So the solution is to use either AndroidX or old Support Library. I recommend to use AndroidX, because Android will not update support libraries after version 28.0.0. See [release notes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions) of Support Library.

Just migrate to AndroidX.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563) is my detailed answer to migrate to AndroidX. I am putting here the needful steps from that answer.

**Before you migrate, it is strongly recommended to backup your project.**

> #### Existing project

- Android Studio > Refactor Menu > Migrate to AndroidX...
- It will analysis and will open Refractor window in bottom. Accept changes to be done.

[image]

> #### New project

Put these flags in your `gradle.properties`

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Check @[Library mappings for equal AndroidX package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563).

Check @[Official page of Migrate to AndroidX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563)

#### [What is Jetifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52518822/6891563)

Comment: Still had an error afterwards, but this answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49525685/1972372

Comment: Please remember to Click "Do refactor" in the bottom left after clicking "Migrate to AndroidX"

Answer (score 97):

In my case, this is working perfectly..
I have added below two line codes inside manifest file

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

Credit goes [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50965002/270197).

[image: Manifest file Example]

Comment: I do not know if I will have a problem in my app later on, but it worked!

Comment: Yes I had a problem: **More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/androidx.core_core.version**

Comment: then i get an error stating tools is not bound to the application tag.

Comment: Can you post full logcat?

Comment: I had to tools to the namespace: https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login/issues/233#issuecomment-293251545

Comment: can you elaborate? @Johannes

Comment: I am getting the error "The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:replace" associated with an element type "application" is not bound."

Comment: This solution works also on Xamarin. I had to add the tools namespace `xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools"` to the `manifest` tag and I used `androidx` as appComponentFactory in place of `whateverString `

Answer (score 30):

### Simple Solutions - migrate into AndroidX

in the `gradle.properties`, just add below two scripts

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

***What was the reason ↓***

> All packages in AndroidX live in a consistent namespace starting with the string androidx. The Support Library packages have been mapped into the corresponding androidx.* packages. For a full mapping of all the old classes and build artifacts to the new ones, see the Package Refactoring page.

**Please see [the Package Refactoring page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)**

Comment: There is no such file gradle.properties in my project. (It is originally created in eclipse years ago and later moved to android studio)

Comment: Oh... I didn't face such a situation, I found below thread that might help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37389861/6917362

Try and do comment please

Comment: Just create that file near main build.gradle if it does not exists and sync the project.

Answer (score 14):

Just remove the android.support dependancy

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

Quoting From Material Guidelines

> If you don’t want to switch over to the new androidx and com.google.android.material packages yet, you can use Material Components via the com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3 dependency.
>
> #### Note: You should not use the com.android.support and com.google.android.dependencies in your app at the same time.

Just removing this dependency works fine

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

Here is complete dependencies example

```
    dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
       implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
   }
```

Comment: This is the most accurate answer.

Comment: @FranMarzoa It is not. What happens when the compat library is imported from another dependency?

Comment: @m0skit0 that you'd have to post a different question here, I guess... ;)

Answer (score 13):

As of Android P, the support libraries have been moved to **AndroidX**

Please do a refactor for your [libs from this page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor).

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor

Answer (score 13):

1. Please go to Refactor->Migrate->Migrate to Android X.
2. Please add this to your `gradle.properties` file:

   ```
   android.enableJetifier=true
   android.useAndroidX=true
   ```

And perform Sync.

Comment: Can you please explain, what is your situation now?

Comment: The project i inherited is half a decade old. I tried to implement new Fabric/Firebase analytics that google is pushing. And that new library is using androidx compatibility libraries, and my project uses AppCompat. Now, i had to deal with tons of dependency updates and stuff. I came to a halt, and then tried various things, including these commands, and i need them because of new Firebase stuff. After i turned this on i got tons of compiler errors. Fixed that but now i have errors coming from ui xml files.. So i will have to abandon everything, and try with older versions.

Comment: After one more hour of manually fixing class namespaces to androidx, it seems to work now. Trouble is, compiler could not detect in xml that for example: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner" needs to be "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner". 
This document came in handy: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Hope it's working now, let me know if anything goes wrong.We shall work on it!

Comment: be very careful with this.  it will effect the entire file tree.  i was working in a real code area and almost refactored hundreds of files.
isolate the projects in their own path before doing this.

also beware if your using fragments it will change the fragment imports to:
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

scary very scary

Answer (score 13):

See This Image and Add This line in your android AndroidManifest.xml

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

[image]

Comment: whatever string means ?

Comment: @KishoreKumar you can add any string name like appName also.

Comment: to be precise, whateverString should be a full class name which extends AppComponentFactory. for example, a custom defined class com.xxx.MyFactory extends AppComponentFactory

Answer (score 12):

Add these lines inside  in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"

android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

Comment: tools is becoming red when adding it. is there other things needed to add?

Comment: No nothing more to add. One reason maybe is ur gradle version is mismatched. Can u show ur AndroidManifest.xml file code?

Comment: I tried migrating to androidx and I keep having Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Here is my android manifest <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:appComponentFactory="@string/texthere"
        >

Comment: Great Solution , Saved my time.

Answer (score 10):

just add these two lines of code to your Manifest file

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

Answer (score 9):

Migrate to `androidX` if it an existing project. If it is new project add these two flags to `Gradle.propeties`

```
android.enableJetifier=true  
android.useAndroidX=true
```

for more detail steps https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx
or check this [What is AndroidX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280090/what-is-androidx)

Answer (score 8):

Follow these steps:

- Goto Refactor and Click Migrate to AndroidX
- Click Do Refactor

Comment: This will not do the entire refactor :(

Answer (score 7):

**Only If you don't want to use androidx**

So in my case, I am using a library that was using androidx but I am not using androidx so when I downgraded that library version the problem was resolved.

In my Case:

```
implementation 'com.github.turing-tech:MaterialScrollBar:13.+'
```

the above-mentioned library makes problem 13.+ will automatically get a new version of the library which using androidx. So I downgraded library version to:

```
implementation 'com.github.turing-tech:MaterialScrollBar:13.2.5'
```

And the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 6):

This issue mainly happened for **old dependencies**.

There have 2 solution:

**First one:**

Update all `old dependencies` and **ClassPaths** from `Project level gradle` files.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

**Second one:**

Your project `Migrate to AndroidX`

**From Android Studio Menu -> Refanctor -> `Migrate to AndroidX`**

Thanks, let me know if anyone help from this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Finally found a quick and easy solution by adding two lines in the `android/build.gradle` file.

```
googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"

firebaseVersion = "17.6.0"
```

Please follow this 100% correct.

Comment: Where do even add this?

Comment: Add this in android/build.gradle file

Comment: @ManojAlwis in which section of build.gradle file we need to put this?

Comment: @KevalLangalia, just add these two lines to android -> build.gradle file .                    
 eg:

 buildscript {

    ext {

        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"

        minSdkVersion = 19

        compileSdkVersion = 28

        targetSdkVersion = 28

        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"

        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"

        firebaseVersion = "17.3.4"

    }

Comment: really helpful... Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Its all about the library versions compatibility

I was facing this strange bug couple of 2 hours.
I resolved this error by doing these steps

**hange your build.gradle dependencies into**

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

to

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
```

Comment: Honestly i did the same and it worked, so i guess its all about the library versions compatibility after merging proccess

Answer (score 5):

All I did was go to the "Refactor" option on the top menu.

Then select "Migrate to AndroidX"

Accept to save the project as a zip file.

Please update Android Studio as well as Gradle to ensure no problems are encountered.

Answer (score 4):

Create new project and compare your build.gradle files and replaced all

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
```

and other dependencies with the same as were in a new project
someting like that

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha3'

implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'

implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-alpha3'
```

And then fixed imports to use androidx in kotlin files.

Comment: Because o some reason, I dont want to use androidx.

Answer (score 4):

**1.Added these codes to at the end of your app/build.gradle:**

```
configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' 
   // the above lib may be old dependencies version       
    }
```

**2.Modified sdk and tools version to 28:**

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
targetSdkVersion  28
```

**3.In your AndroidManifest.xml file, you should add two line:**

```
<application
    android:name=".YourApplication"
    android:appComponentFactory="AnyStrings"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

**Or Simply**

- Go to Refactor (Studio -> Menu -> Refactor)
- Click the Migrate to AndroidX. it's working
- it's working.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not intend to migrate to AndroidX follow the below steps

1. In terminal type gradlew app:dependencies
2. After dependencies are shown in the window press Ctrl+f and type androidX
3. You will find all the dependencies which are using androidx lib internally you may have to downgrade that or use alternative for that to ensure it is no longer using androidX libs internally.

Answer (score 2):

First of all be sure to add this line in **manifest tag**

```
xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Then add tools replace your suggested one in Android studio

Answer (score 2):

- Go to Refactor ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4TQn.jpg) )
- Click the Migrate to AndroidX. it's working
- it's working.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
```

Rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem for three days.

It is like android wants us to either use Kotlin Or AndroidX, they are doing away with Android.

But this is how I solved it.

- I migrated my project to AndroidX. This does not bring in any errors related to this issue in question, It updates files respectively. No method, class or variable name needs to be changed in your application.

NB: You must be using the latest Libraries (build.grudle file) in the latest stable version of android studio 3.4.1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this is the proper answer or not but it worked for me

Increase Gridle Wrapper Property

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

and Build Gridle to

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

its showing error because of the version.

Comment: I think the string should be androidx.core.app.AppComponentFactory, arbitrary strings will cause random errors some times.,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when working with Groupie.
`implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.3.0'`

I solved it by changing version to `implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.1.0'`

Answer (score 0):

In may case I didn't want to pass to androidX. And I have to check my last changes. I figure out that the new component was --> `lottie 2.8.0`

So I downgrade it to: `implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Change proguardFile in build.gradle (Module: app) to the following

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

instead of

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For solving this issue i would recommend to define explicitly the version for the ext variables
at the `android/build.gradle` at your root project

```
ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0" // default: "+"
    firebaseVersion = "15.0.2" // default: "+"

    // Other settings
    compileSdkVersion = <Your compile SDK version> // default: 23
    buildToolsVersion = "<Your build tools version>" // default: "23.0.1"
    targetSdkVersion = <Your target SDK version> // default: 23
    supportLibVersion = "<Your support lib version>" // default: 23.1.1
}
```

reference 
https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1109#issuecomment-506414941

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue,
for your android studio, you just change the android Gradle plugin version 3.3.2
and Gradle version is 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

in my case i am add in manifest file `

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

application tag of course,
It will work

Answer (score 0):

if you are using capacitor, upgrade to capacitor/core 2.0.1 or up in your package.json

Answer (score -3):

**change your build.gradle dependencies into**

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

**or**

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```