# Manifest merger failed after adding : annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0"

Tags: android, manifest, android-livedata

Doing a tutorial about LiveData & ViewModel. 
In build.gradle I added:

```
// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"
```

Project synced without a problem. Then I added (1):

```
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0"
```

but sync failed so I added (2) (I have Java 10.0.2 installed):

```
// alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.0.0"
```

But I get the same manifest merger failed error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-28:19 to override.
```

Added to Android Manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
```

Sync fails:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple
>   errors, see logs

Comment: Fixed the sync issue. Added: // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version" and removed line. I removed tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" from Manifest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Material and appcompat Manifest merger failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793345/android-material-and-appcompat-manifest-merger-failed)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not setting up the project correctly to work with Android's new AndroidX support library.  See [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/).  The quickest solution is to use the pre-androidx dependencies shown in [LiveData deps](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#lifecycle).  Otherwise refer to the previous link to set up AndroidX correctly in your project.  This can be accomplished pretty easily by adding `android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true` into your gradle.properties. Those cause the compiler to convert android support libraries to there corresponding AndroidX libraries.