# Android Manifest merger failed || Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I am working on a App using Firebase. I got a issue which needs to get solved. When i go to run the app it shows in **build**.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-31:19 to override.

I searched the whole internet to solve the issue failed. I also added

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
```

in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file. I also followed the answer of [This Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793345/android-material-and-appcompat-manifest-merger-failed) but it didn't work for me saying

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

How can i solve this problem. What should i do now.

**build.grable**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.offtechitbd.e_orderapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'

    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: when question is related to manifest file, why have you posted gradle file instead of manifest ?

Answer (score 1):

-Try adding this lines to application tag in manifest.

```
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
    android:appComponentFactory="androidx"
```

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip, in the bottom of the manifest you can access the "Merged Manifest" to check the errors.

[image]

If you can't figure out the erros, post your manifest so we can help.

Comment: Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:10 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 9 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

Comment: If possible post the whole manifest, so we can take a look at this lines.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i was using `implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'`
and the `android-image-cropper:2.8.+'` is Update to support library to **AndroidX**.
So i just changed the version to this

> implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'

Now the app is working fine.