# Manifest Merger Failed error, also two sync modules

Tags: android

I got a project which is showing some Manifest merger failed error. I tried many solutions including Migration to androidx also but the project is using some libraries which shows error on migration to androidx, so I can't migrate it to androidx. Please provide a solution to this problem. Also, this project is showing two sync modules, why I don't understand. I have attached a screenshot of my project error.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appetiser.kookaborrow"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 114
    versionName "1.0.14"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.6.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation('com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.4@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.5.0@aar'
implementation 'be.billington.calendar.recurrencepicker:library:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ec2:2.3.3'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.3'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.kbeanie:multipicker:1.1.31@aar'
implementation 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'

implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.1.1'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Try to paste the actual code and not screenshots.

Comment: This error might have been caused by one or more dependency that you are using in this project. Those dependency might be using androidX. You might need to find that library and use older version of it. I'm not sure about this tho!!

Comment: check this question :https://stackoverflow.com/a/53977445/6737471

Answer (score 1):

you need to add these two lines in you `gradle.properties` file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: This will migrate my project to androidx, which I don't want.

Comment: there is no other way to use with out-migrating.

Answer (score 0):

add following line inside your application tag of your `manifest.xml`

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
```

Note that you need to write inside your `manifest` file. **not** in build/manifest.xml

You can try adding:

```
android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
```

To the tag  in your manifest.

Comment: It showing error
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Comment: Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:22 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 21 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

Answer (score 0):

So after wasting a day on this error, I finally solved it. The two errors that I have mentioned in my questions were due to two libraries, one was deprecated and another one was not updated, so I removed the deprecated one and reduce the version of another one which was not updated, this solved my problem. This is not compulsory to migrate your project to androidx, this is because there may be some third party library which may not be convertible, that may cause an error. If there would be any error like this, its good to first check all those libraries that causing error, and solve it or remove it or try to downgrade its version.
Have a nice day.