# Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-manifest, android-support-library

Hi I was working on a Project where I used many dependencies of Libraries. It was working fine but suddenly it has started to report errors. I am new in using Libraries dependencies and I am using Firebase database and storage and also have added google-services.json under app folder. I couldn't understand where the problem lies.
Thanks for help in advance

Following is the Error list

`Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

> Configure project :app
>   Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>
> Task :app:buildInfoDebugLoader
>   Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugSources
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
>   Parsing json file: C:\Users\alexa\AndroidStudioProjects\eCommerceProject\app\google-services.json
>
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
>   C:\Users\alexa\AndroidStudioProjects\eCommerceProject\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
>       Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-36:19 to override.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

> Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
  >   is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
  >   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-36:19 to override.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s
14 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 10 up-to-date

Comment: put your google-services.json file in project level app folder not in android level app folder .

Answer (score 7):

Try Adding two lines in `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

These two lines automatically resolved my dependency conflicts between google's files and third party dependencies.

Hope it works for you !

Comment: But it has started to show several errors on import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Comment: can you share the error log??

Comment: logcat is tooo large and its not allowing me to put it all over here so i am using this link https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U2NsiL-qDKiRzFnq_0mqDYX9RsU5UEEdBPgmKq7XTtQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: try adding this inside Application tag in manifest file  .tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"

Comment: try solutions from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793345/android-material-and-appcompat-manifest-merger-failed