# error in implement google maps default mapsactivity

Tags: android

I want to implement google maps in my app.I added a google maps activity and created a key.When using MapsAcivity.java file shown some error codes.I tried many solutions but didn't worked.

MapsAcivity-error code

> private GoogleMap mMap = 
>   ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Console error

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
>
> Error:
>       Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-45:19 to override.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54533702/10877674 check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using material library which is part of AndroidX. If you are not aware of AndroidX, please go through this answer.

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54533702/10877674

Answer (score 0):

You are using the appcompat library with androidx library thats why you are having this error. Either use Androidx or Appcompat.