# After migrate to AndroidX: "Unresolved reference: ..."

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I got some errors in my application and found this solution: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54533702/11720147)

Now, nothing works. When I run the project, I get errors like

```
Unresolved reference: adapter   
Unresolved reference: currentItem   
Unresolved reference: addOnPageChangeListener
```

Those errors coming from the MainActivity. I added there a ViewPager a few days ago. Since I migrated to androidX, the viewpager shows a lot of errors.

```
lateinit var myAdapter: myPagerAdapter

// view_pager from activity_main.xml

view_pager.adapter = myAdapter
    btn_next.setOnClickListener {
        view_pager.currentItem++
    }

view_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(p0: Int) {

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Check the xml-file and change

```
<androidx.support.v4.view.ViewPager
...
```

to:

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 tabLayout!!.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            viewPager2!!.currentItem = tab.position
        }
        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
    })
```