# i am getting a Manifest error in my flutter project,How to solve this?

Tags: flutter

i am getting this error while building the app

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-69:19 to override.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Material and appcompat Manifest merger failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793345/android-material-and-appcompat-manifest-merger-failed). Most likely it's an issue between Android X and the support libraries.

Comment: i am also following this but no result yet

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more in your question about what you already tried yourself, your project setup, which plugins you are using etc. That makes it easier for us to try and help you.