# Android Google Map Gradle dependency error

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using sample google map V2 in my app. In gradle file if I using below lib its working fine but need to implement Multi Dex

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

If I using only google map service it's not able to generate build,I am getting error in Android Manifest

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

Error:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:15:17-25:19 to override.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.samplemap"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resValue "string", "google_maps_key", (project.findProperty("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY") ?: "")
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'(Not getting error but need to enable multi dex)
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'(getting error)
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

error in code if using maps lib,refer image below

[image]

Comment: Post your gradle file, then it will be easy to understand the problem

Comment: you can add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" is yout manifest to get rid of the problem. it will override the default value set from map dependency.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793345/android-material-and-appcompat-manifest-merger-failed/53202089

Comment: @darwin when adding tools:replace getting error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to SupportMapFragment

Comment: which is not related to this issue, you must use SupportMapFragment if instead of  Fragment in your code

Comment: @darwin see the attached image

Comment: you should use     <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        map:mapType="normal"
        map:uiCompass="false"
        map:uiRotateGestures="false"
        map:uiScrollGestures="false"
        map:uiTiltGestures="false"
        map:uiZoomControls="false"
        map:uiZoomGestures="false" />  as map container in your xml file, then it can be cast to supportMapFragment

Comment: @darwin same code I used in my xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196550/discussion-between-darwin-and-appukrb).

Answer (score 0):

Actually The error is related to new Android Studio version.
So the solution is you must migrate your project to Android X. The issue will solved automatically.

```
 Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX
```

May be it can cause some error, but as per new update this is mandatory to move into AndroidX

Comment: Why should I migrate to my project for using maps?

Comment: because android is upgraded to next level.