# I have a problem with the suggestion of adding 'tools: replace = "android: appComponentFactory" to the xml file

Tags: android, firebase, android-support-library, androidx

I have a problem with my android studio with the following information;

```
console
```

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>         is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>         Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-60:19 to override.

I have tried adding the suggestion to my `xml` file, but almost all of my manifest files have errors

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.persmaeuridice.rppkurikulum2013revisi"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.persmaeuridice.rppkurikulum2013revisi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-9531726632194033~6789886788" />

        <activity android:name=".Buton2Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Buton3Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Buton4Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Buton5Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Buton6Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".KelasviiActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Paud34GanjilActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Paud23GanjilActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Paud23GenapActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Paud34GenapActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Paud56GanjilActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Paud56GenapActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".KelasXActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".KelasXIActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".KelasXIIActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".KelasVIIIActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".KelasIXActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".awal" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku1" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku2" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku3" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku4" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku5" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku6" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku7" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku8" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku9" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku10" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku11" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku12" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku13" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku14" />
        <activity android:name=".buku.buku15" />
        <activity android:name=".Buton7Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The simple solution is just migrate to AndroidX . Otherwise you will end up changing library versions over and over .

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest add tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" in the application tag like below

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. seems google play service is not implemented.

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.+'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.+'
```

Add Google Play Service at the last line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: for more solution follow this. Manoj Answer work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56696041/4923046

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions to this problem.

**First**

Migrate your project into `AndroidX`

**Second**

Add these lines inside your `application tag` like below.

> tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
>
> android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" 
        android:appComponentFactory="whateverString" 
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```