# How to fix manifest merger failed with multiple errors?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-support-library, androidx

I want to use google admob in my android app so i added this library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
```

but when i run the project this error happens  manifest merger failed with multiple errors .

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Answer (score 2):

You must migrate your project to AndroidX: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53242928/336658
or you can try to use an old version of play-service-ads

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
```