# how to resolve error after adding ExpoPlayer dependency

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to use Google ExoPlayer but when I add this dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.4'
```

to my dependencies I got this error .

```java
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-26:19 to override.
```

also I add `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to application tag in manifest but didn't work. 
what should I do ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793345/android-material-and-appcompat-manifest-merger-failed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason being is you are using the older version of support libraries. You need to either migrate to AndroidX or add following lines in the gradle.properties file.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

in manifest add

```
<application
        ...
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using andoidx then add below two lines in
**gradle.properties**

```
 android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: if you are using androidx and not added these both fields true then this type of errors occurs.