# How to create a new Android Wear project and run it on a device?

Tags: android, wear-os

The question says it all. Unfortunately it's not as simple as creating a new project, connecting a device and pushing the run button. Here are the details:

I'm trying to create a new **Wear OS only** app (i.e. no phone or tablet support). API Level is set to 28 (Android 8), with a Blank Wear Activity. After finishing the new project wizzard, Android Studio prints the following welcome message in shiny red letters:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-35:19 to override.
```

Following the recommendation and adding `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to `<application>` element at AndroidManifest.xml changed the error message to:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication(AndroidBuilder.java:540)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeManifests.doFullTaskAction(MergeManifests.java:173)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
```

That did not make it any better... Reverting the manifest modification and googling the root cause (Manifest merger failed) seemed to be the better approach, which lead to [this answer here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52564822/3921848) that suggests to add the following two lines at `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

And finally it builds! However, the app instantly crashes when trying to run it on the watch:

```
   --------- beginning of crash
2019-09-04 15:34:08.435 7341-7341/weartest.com.weartest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: weartest.com.weartest, PID: 7341
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{weartest.com.weartest/weartest.com.weartest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.wearable.jar", zip file "/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:419)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2669)
        at weartest.com.weartest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
2019-09-04 15:34:08.437 7331-7331/? W/app_process: Could not reserve sentinel fault page
2019-09-04 15:34:08.459 7341-7341/weartest.com.weartest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/weartest.com.weartest-siv6gP9D5m9OQwHrsoFU8g==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:35)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:693)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:727)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:954)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5639)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
                ... 6 more
```

So this isn't the right fix neither...

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong here? Creating a new project and running it on a device should work out of the box, but it seems there's something seriously broken.

Btw. Android Studio Version 3.2.1, with SDK Platform Tools 29.0.2 and SDK Tools 26.1.1 is used. SDKs 21 til 29 are installed.

Any advise how to get an empty wear project running is appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some problem with dependencies.
Actually, I have never faced issue like that, first suggestion would be 
to update andorid studio, then create new wear os project and try to run it without any changes.

If this would not help, some other solution might be to remove usages of wear classes and all wear specific dependencies and leave just

> < uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

in the manifest file and then try to run default Android activity.