# merge manifest error when add material dependency

Tags: android, material-design, androidx, android-design-library, material-components-android

when add

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
```

in gradle file and build the error is :

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.1.0-rc03] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-36:19 to override.
```

And when add `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` in manifest file , i have another error
new error message is :Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

my geadle file :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.saat.ali.hozorghiab"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 6
    versionName '1.6'
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'

implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:2.0.4'
//testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'
```

}

Comment: Share your gradle file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Material and appcompat Manifest merger failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793345/android-material-and-appcompat-manifest-merger-failed)

Comment: Have you migrated to androidX?

Comment: change all dependency to android x or change all to appcompat. if you are using material dependency then just change all to android x dependencies. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: @SagarNayak im not using android x in my app

Comment: what is the need for the material artifact then? any specific thing you want from this dependency? you can always use com.android.support:design as an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [official doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#new-namespace-and-androidx) of the Material Components library:

> If your app currently depends on the original Design Support Library, you can make use of the **Refactor to AndroidX**… option provided by Android Studio. Doing so will update your app's dependencies and code to use the newly packaged `androidx` and `com.google.android.material` libraries.
>
> If you don't want to switch over to the new `androidx` and `com.google.android.material` packages yet, you can use Material Components via the `com.android.support:design:28.0.0` dependency.
>
> Note: **You should not use** the `com.android.support` and `com.google.android.material` dependencies in your app **at the same time**.

You have to use **AndroidX** libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try migrating to AndroidX, to do this go to Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX, most of the problems about manifest merger are goes away with AndroidX.
and the cool part is that migration is so safe, never had any problem with migrating my projects.