# android studio manifest file issue

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, androidx

I'm getting an error while building the project. It seems to be a conflict between androidx and support libraries, but androix isn't set in the project.

The error:

```
Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
            is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
            Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-154:19 to override.
```

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

My build gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 16
        versionName "2.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.warkiz.tickseekbar:tickseekbar:0.1.3'
    implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.4.1'

}
```

gradle.proprieties

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decou

pled_projects

# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Comment: You are using support libraries and androidx together

Comment: Post your build.gradle, but you have to migrate all libraries to androidx.

Comment: there are two ways to solve this issue first : decrease `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1` gradle version 18.1.1 to 11.0.0   second : migrate your app to andridx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Material and appcompat Manifest merger failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793345/android-material-and-appcompat-manifest-merger-failed)

Answer (score 0):

One or more of your dependencies seems to be loading androidx to your project and 
AndroidX is supposed to be a substitute to all the support libraries, you shouldn't use them together, as they will override classes from one another. Take a look at the [AndroidX Doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).

You'll either need to find and remove the libraries that are using androidx from your project or migrate it to androidx. I would suggest **migrating the project entirely to androidx**.

It is easy to do, and the support libraries are getting outdated anyway. And you'll find androidx easier to use.

Comment: but sir i dont use androidx

Comment: i updated code again there no android x=true emm i tihni iwll donwgrade android stuido cz i installed latest one

Comment: Specifically, the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1` library has androidx dependencies.