# updated to android studio 3.3.0 and got this message

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

updated to android studio 3.3.0 and got this warning.

`WARNING: API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getAssemble(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
Affected Modules: app`

what does it mean use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
where should i put that.

Not able to Build

Comment: _"what does it mean use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line"_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216248/passing-p-parameters-to-gradle-from-android-studio/36509321

Comment: You can look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54197066/2148666) to see an alternative way to achieve the same

Comment: "Not able to Build" is nonsense. This is just a warning.
That will probably be a problem in early 2020 if nobody has a solution. The stacktrace probably would just tell you about a problem with thread in JAVA that you can't solve...