# How to fix could not load gradle properties in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

When I create a new project in the android studio I get a Gradle error:

```
Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Kotlin Projects\Apps\500Days\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
```

I don't know what's wrong, please what do I do?? and what caused this it was working fine just yesterday.

Here's a photo of it on screen just in case:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just create a file called gradle.properties in your root project:

```
root
|--gradle.properties
|--build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
|--app
|----build.gradle
```

Then add inside the file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
```

More Detail [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380417/android-studio-where-is-gradle-properties-file)

Comment: There is already a gradle.properties file, Should I added this in there??

Comment: You can Delete and Recreate new on . please follow more detail attach link